# C++ object(int)

Tags: c++, oop

I have an exam in 2 days with the main given and i need to make all the classes work over that main. I am stuck at a line of code and was hoping you can help me. What function do i need to overload to be able to call this line:

(Lets say i have a class A and an object a that is of type A. The class has an int array. With the next line i need to get the biggest value below the given parameter)

```
cout << a(1200);
```

I can't seem to make it work, i tried casting to int altho it didn't quite make sense but i found somewhere that idea and thought to give it a try.

Comment: If that is part of your exam it should be in your class notes. Look for something on the topic of *operator overloading*

Comment: You should post your attempt...

Comment: @Isma the attempt makes no sense and it was only a cast override...

Comment: Yeah  but it will help you avoid the down-votes, if you at least tried something it doesn't look like you want someone to do your school work for you.

Comment: If you were really interested in learning you would have followed my initial advice and researched *operator overloading*. It doesn't take much to find that you can overload [the function call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other). Since you didn't do that I assume you expected someone to present you the code on a silver plater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to overload `<<` operator. For instance:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)  
{  
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;  
    return os;  
}
```

If `a()` isn't constructor, but only a `()` operator overloaded which I assumed changes the `a` field of the class `A` to the parameter provided inside `()` your code could look something like this:

```
 class A{
      public:
      int a;
      A(int a){
          this->a = a;
      }
      A(){}

      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& dt);

      A operator()(int n){ //changes the current a to n
      this->a = n;
      return *this;
      }

      ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& objectA){  
      os << objectA.a<<endl;
      return os;  
      } 

    int main()
    {
        A a(1500);
        cout<<a(1200);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I will try that now, thank you very much

Comment: Not working, i also need another parameter (int)

Comment: @AlexandruSandu well, you have to modify this to suit your example. `Date` object is `a` class in your case. And in the `os<<...` line you should print fields from the class `a`. Also this method should be inside of `a` class.

Comment: Yes, i know that, for me it will be: ostream& operator<<(ostream&, A a){...} but as i said in the question i need to call cout<<a(1200); with this function i can't do that because i don't have the parameter (1200)

Comment: @AlexandruSandu Edited, hope that helps.